# Extend many standard methods to a new custom vector type

Tags: julia

I build a new vector type:

```
type MyType
    x::Vector{Float64}
end
```

I want to extend lots of the standard methods, eg addition, subtraction, element-wise comparison, etc to my new type. Do I need to define a method definition for each of them, eg:

```
+(a::MyType, b::MyType) = a.x + b.x
-(a::MyType, b::MyType) = a.x - b.x
.<(a::MyType, b::MyType) = a.x .< b.x
```

or is there some syntactic short-cut I can use here?

Comment: Perhaps some metaprogramming like [in base/float16.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/float16.jl#L144).

Comment: @rickhg12hs I've never had to look into metaprogramming before. I guess it is about time... many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example using [Julia's Metaprogramming](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#code-generation):

```
for op in (:+, :-, :.<)
    @eval ($op)(a::MyType, b::MyType) = ($op)(a.x, b.x)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can inherit from `AbstractArray` and define a very small interface to get all the basic array operations for free:

```
type MyType <: AbstractVector{Float64}
    x::Vector{Float64}
end
Base.linearindexing(::Type{MyType}) = Base.LinearFast()
Base.size(m::MyType) = size(m.x)
Base.getindex(m::MyType,i::Int) = m.x[i]
Base.setindex!(m::MyType,v::Float64,i::Int) = m.x[i] = v
Base.similar(m::MyType, dims::Tuple{Int}) = MyType(Vector{Float64}(dims[1]))
```

Let's test this:

```
julia> MyType([1,2,3]) + MyType([3,2,1])
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 4.0
 4.0
 4.0

julia> MyType([1,2,3]) - MyType([3,2,1])
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -2.0
  0.0
  2.0

julia> MyType([1,2,3]) .< MyType([3,2,1])
3-element BitArray{1}:
  true
 false
 false
```