# User defined type in Julia for "marking" purposes

Tags: arrays, types, julia, user-defined-types

In my code I need to keep track of two kinds of data items, namely the original data items and the transformed data items.
Both original and transformed data items I store as `Array{Float64,1}`.
However, I need to keep track if a data item is a transformed one or not as some functions in my code work with the original data items and some with the transformed ones.

In order to ensure correctness and avoid ever passing a transformed data item to a function that is supposed to work with the original data item, I was thinking that I could create a type called `Transformed`. This type could be used in the function declarations thus enforcing correctness.

Of course I looked in the documentation, but this did not help me enough.
I guess what I need to do is something like:

```
primitive type Transformed :< Array{Float64,1} end
```

but of course this doesn't work (it is not even a primitive!)

Do I have to go for a struct? any suggestions? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you likely want a `struct` or a `mutable struct` containing an `Array{Float64, 1}`. You can learn more about these in the Julia manual section on composite types (i.e. structs): https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Composite-Types-1

A simple example would be:

```
struct Transformed
  data::Array{Float64, 1}
end
```

Comment: Note, though, that `Transformed` objects won't act like arrays. You must explicitly work with the `.data` field, but I assume this works for the "safety" factor requested.

Comment: @user1438310 Agreed this is pretty much a classic case for using a `struct`. Note, if you want your array `struct` to behave like a regular array without having to reference the `.data` field, you might also want to check out the [interfaces](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/interfaces/) section of the manual.

Comment: @ColinTBowers: Ideally, I would like to avoid using `struct`. I had a look at the interfaces section, but I was lost. Would it be possible to detail how to make `Transformed` behave just like an array? i.e. with respect to indexing, addition, multiplication and so on.

Comment: @user1438310 Why would you want to avoid using `struct`? Defining your own immutable types via `struct` and then calling them via multiple dispatch is basically the core feature of julia. This is like saying you want to use MatLab but you don't want to use arrays. Regarding interfaces, that's probably a new stack overflow question, rather than something that should be discussed in the comments.

Comment: @ColinTBowers: I accidentally wrote the wrong thing, sorry! I actually like the idea of a `struct` but I want to avoid constantly referencing the field `data`. I did have a look at the interfaces section of the Julia manual, but got lost. Would it be possible to detail how to make `Transforme`d behave just like an array? i.e. with respect to indexing, addition, multiplication and so on. Thanks.

Comment: @user1438310 As I said, that is really a new question, and not something that should be dealt with in the comments. Ask it as a new question, something like "Making a new array type behave like a regular array in julia v1.0". Make sure you include v1.0, as this question has already been answered for older versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363519/extend-many-standard-methods-to-a-new-custom-vector-type) (but quite a lot has changed since then).

Comment: @ColinTBowers Thanks for your time. Quite rightly, I will open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to access your arrays with the `.data` field you might consider using `StaticArrays`. There might be some other already existing data structures, but this was the first I could think of.

You can declare these with `SVector` or [with some macros](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl). The benefit of this is that then you can check whether an array is a StaticArray or a regular one quite easily, but you can just use them as regular arrays.

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> original_array = SVector(1.5,2,3)
3-element StaticArrays.SArray{Tuple{3},Float64,1,3}:
 1.5
 2.0
 3.0

julia> transformed_array = Array{Float64,1}(original_array + 1.3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.8
 3.3
 4.3

julia> # these will give you StaticArrays
       original_array + transformed_array
3-element StaticArrays.SArray{Tuple{3},Float64,1,3}:
 4.3
 5.3
 7.3

julia> transformed_array + original_array
3-element StaticArrays.SArray{Tuple{3},Float64,1,3}:
 4.3
 5.3
 7.3

julia> # matrix multiplication still works
       original_array' * transformed_array
23.699999999999996

julia> original_array * transformed_array'
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 4.2  4.95   6.45
 5.6  6.6    8.6
 8.4  9.9   12.9

julia> # same for reductions
       sum(transformed_array)
10.399999999999999
```

One obvious drawback is that you can't grow these StaticArrays. But I assumed if you want to keep your original values then this is not a problem anyways.

Also, as shown above, be careful when operating on them as you might get StaticArrays back. Then you will need to explicitly convert the results into Arrays.

Comment: Thanks for this answer too, but for my particular case I will go for the insert suggesting the struct solution as in the future I will need to keep track of more than just the two kinds of data items that I have for now.